# How to mark to mark the return type of a function as a promise of a custom type

Tags: typescript, bluebird

I have a code snippet that looks like this

```
import * as Promise from 'bluebird';
import {Response} from '../commonInterfaces/httpService';

getCall(url: string, accessToken: string, extraHeaders: object): Promise<Response> {
    let headers = this.getHeaders(accessToken, extraHeaders);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request({
            url: url,
            method: "GET",
            withCredentials: false,
            json: true,
            headers: headers
        }, (err: Error, response: Response) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err)
            } else {
                resolve(response)
            }
        });
    });
}
```

and Response is an interface

```
interface Response {statusCode: number, body: object}
```

and i am getting the following error

```
[ts]
Type 'Bluebird<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Bluebird<Response>'.
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Response'.
Property 'statusCode' is missing in type '{}'.
```

what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the compiler doesn't infer the type from calling `resolve(response)`.
You can "help" it by specifying the generic constraint yourself:

```
return new Promise<Response>((resolve, reject) => { ... });
```